# Why is my large DDP document losing symbology in later pages of PDF export?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, symbology, arcgis-10.3, pdf, data-driven-pages

The map document is 77 pages long and it seems that later pages are losing some symbols for features. The scale isn't changing, so it is not an issue of scale based displays. Any thoughts?

Comment: Can you add or link to a couple screenshots to your question so we can see what you're talking about? I've had many problems with DDP but this is a new one to me.

Comment: This is a problem with a client's document so I'm not really at liberty to share any images of it. It is an electric system and they are losing recloser symbols around page 50 they simply stop appearing. I've exported it a few different times just to make sure my computer wasn't just being cranky.

Comment: Have you tried splitting it up into a number of smaller mapbooks and exporting them separately?

Comment: You might try one of the following which have reportedly fixed other DDP export to pdf issues: 1. export using arcpy mapping instead of the GUI, 2. change the pdf compression from jpeg to lzw, or 3. disable background 64 bit geoprocessing.  For arcpy try:

mxd = arcpy.mapping.MapDocument("CURRENT")
ddp = mxd.dataDrivenPages
ddp.exportToPDF(r"C:\Path\To\output.pdf")